# How can I recursively input parameters into this function with an initial value?

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, genetic

so I have this function which takes in an array of arrays and outputs an array of arrays with different values (I am attempting genetic programming breeding function).

So my problem is as follows: I have a main function which is called `evolve(population)` which takes in an array of arrays and outputs a new one. I would like to keep calling this function on successive populations, however, I'm not quite sure how to?

So we have an initial array x and we pass it into `evolve(x)` which outputs a new array of arrays y, now I would like to pass `evolve(y)` into my function and so on for z amount of times (in a for loop). Can this be done?

Comment: Your question asks for 'recursively', but the explanation looks 'iteratively' to me.  Is there a reason you want it to be recursive?

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job quite nicely;

```
population = [1, 2, 3, 4]  # any list
z = 10  # evolve 10 times

for i in range(z):
    population = evolve(population)
```